# Correct way to test a function that has some unused parameter

Tags: python, unit-testing

Rather than coding this is a question on how to correctly test a function.

**Background**

I am using pytest to test a function. Now a bit about the background of this function

Originally the developers wrote a function like

```
def the_function(first_df, second_df)
```

However, it seems that they realized something was not working with their function so they modified it to

```
def the_function(first_df, second_df, third_df)
```

I have seen the code and in this new implementation they quit using `second_df` at all for their logic. Now the logical thing would have been to rewrite the function as `def the_function(first_df,third_df)` but they didn't. They just left `second_df` there unused

So now I have to write some unit tests for this function

**The question**

Since `second_df` is not being used at all, I am thinking of preparing some data needed for `first_df` and `third_df` and just enter an empty dataframe for `second_df` (since it is not being used at all)

Would this strategy be OK?

I am a bit worried because since one of the goals of unit testing is to keep any rewriting or refactoring of the function to introduce errors, what if in the future someone refactors `the_function` actually using `second_df`...

On the other hand if someone does that, and then test the function, surely an empty dataframe will signal an error, but in that case, will the unit test have to be rewritten?

Comment: I would simply pass an empty dataframe or even `None` if it is not being used at all. If someone refactors `the_function` in the future your unit test will fail and they will investigate what went wrong. That's the whole point of unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

If someone *refactors* the function, they can't change the *behaviour* of the function. That's the definition of a refactor.

So if someone does indeed do a "change function signature" refactoring to get rid of that unused second data frame, they'd also have to update the unit tests that call that function (and all other callers), ideally in a careful step-by-step way. Anyway, no issue there.

If someone changes the *behaviour* of the function so that now it *does* something with all three dataframes, then *of course* that will break the existing unit test, and that's good, because obviously if the function is now supposed to do something differently, the unit test must reflect that.

As for what *you* should do: Why not do the "remove unused parameter" refactoring right now? Following the "leave the place better than you found it" ethics of little-by-little refactoring.